# How to pass a type as a method parameter in Java

Tags: java, types

In Java, how can you pass a type as a parameter (or declare as a variable)?

I don't want to pass an *instance* of the type but the type itself (eg. int, String, etc).

In C#, I can do this:

```
private void foo(Type t)
{
    if (t == typeof(String)) { ... }
    else if (t == typeof(int)) { ... }
}

private void bar()
{
    foo(typeof(String));
}
```

Is there a way in Java without passing an *instance* of type t?
Or do I have to use my own int constants or enum?
Or is there a better way?

Edit: Here is the requirement for foo:
Based on type t, it generates a different short, xml string.
The code in the if/else will be very small (one or two lines) and will use some private class variables.

Comment: You can pass the Class type like private void foo(Class c) and use like foo(String.class)

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You could pass a [`Class<T>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) in.

```
private void foo(Class<?> cls) {
    if (cls == String.class) { ... }
    else if (cls == int.class) { ... }
}

private void bar() {
    foo(String.class);
}
```

**Update**: the OOP way depends on the functional requirement. Best bet would be an interface defining `foo()` and two concrete implementations implementing `foo()` and then just call `foo()` on the implementation you've at hand. Another way may be a `Map<Class<?>, Action>` which you could call by `actions.get(cls)`. This is easily to be combined with an interface and concrete implementations: `actions.get(cls).foo()`.

Comment: I'll add details of the requirement to the question.

Comment: I've decided to go with the simple version for now since the types in question will always be primitive (int, string, etc).  However, I will definitely keep the oop way in mind.  Thanks.

Comment: `String` is not a primitive in Java ;)

Comment: @Padawan - still not enough to go on.  The answer from BalusC using Map is sufficient.  You're right to accept it.

Comment: Also you can use `Class<?> cls` in something other than comparison. While you can't write: `cls value = (cls) aCollection.iterator().next();` you can call cls.cast(aCollection.iterator().next()); [Class javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)

Comment: Can you do this also for subtypes? Class<?> extends xxx or something?

Comment: What difference is there between `<?>` and `<T>`? Is the question mark a valid variable name for types?

Comment: @mazunki: The `<?>` is just a wildcard. It basically means "any kind of type".

Answer (score 23):

I had a similar question, so I worked up a complete runnable answer below. What I needed to do is pass a class (C) to an object (O) of an unrelated class and have that object (O) emit new objects of class (C) back to me when I asked for them.

The example below shows how this is done.  There is a MagicGun class that you load with any subtype of the Projectile class (Pebble, Bullet or NuclearMissle). The interesting is you load it with subtypes of Projectile, but not actual objects of that type. The MagicGun creates the actual object when it's time to shoot.

### The Output

```
You've annoyed the target!
You've holed the target!
You've obliterated the target!
click
click
```

### The Code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PassAClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MagicGun gun = new MagicGun();
        gun.loadWith(Pebble.class);
        gun.loadWith(Bullet.class);
        gun.loadWith(NuclearMissle.class);
        //gun.loadWith(Object.class);   // Won't compile -- Object is not a Projectile
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            try {
                String effect = gun.shoot().effectOnTarget();
                System.out.printf("You've %s the target!\n", effect);
            } catch (GunIsEmptyException e) {
                System.err.printf("click\n");
            }
        }
    }
}

class MagicGun {
    /**
     * projectiles holds a list of classes that extend Projectile. Because of erasure, it
     * can't hold be a List<? extends Projectile> so we need the SuppressWarning. However
     * the only way to add to it is the "loadWith" method which makes it typesafe. 
     */
    private @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") List<Class> projectiles = new ArrayList<Class>();
    /**
     * Load the MagicGun with a new Projectile class.
     * @param projectileClass The class of the Projectile to create when it's time to shoot.
     */
    public void loadWith(Class<? extends Projectile> projectileClass){
        projectiles.add(projectileClass);
    }
    /**
     * Shoot the MagicGun with the next Projectile. Projectiles are shot First In First Out.
     * @return A newly created Projectile object.
     * @throws GunIsEmptyException
     */
    public Projectile shoot() throws GunIsEmptyException{
        if (projectiles.isEmpty())
            throw new GunIsEmptyException();
        Projectile projectile = null;
        // We know it must be a Projectile, so the SuppressWarnings is OK
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") Class<? extends Projectile> projectileClass = projectiles.get(0);
        projectiles.remove(0);
        try{
            // http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/ObjectReflectioncreatenewinstance.htm
            projectile = projectileClass.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        return projectile;
    }
}

abstract class Projectile {
    public abstract String effectOnTarget();
}

class Pebble extends Projectile {
    @Override public String effectOnTarget() {
        return "annoyed";
    }
}

class Bullet extends Projectile {
    @Override public String effectOnTarget() {
        return "holed";
    }
}

class NuclearMissle extends Projectile {
    @Override public String effectOnTarget() {
        return "obliterated";
    }
}

class GunIsEmptyException extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4574971294051632635L;
}
```

Comment: I understand that you're trying to demo passing a type to a method, and I like the example generally, but the simple question this raises is why wouldn't you just load the magic gun with new instances of projectiles rather than complicating matters like this? Also don't suppress the warnings fix them with `List<Class<? extends Projectile>> projectiles = new ArrayList<Class<? extends Projectile>>()`. The Projectile class should be an interface, and the serial isn't necessary for your example,

Comment: The only reason I could come up with is that reading the class name might be useful. http://pastebin.com/v9UyPtWT But then, you could use an enum. http://pastebin.com/Nw939Js1

Answer (score 15):

Oh, but that's ugly, non-object-oriented code.  The moment you see "if/else" and "typeof", you should be thinking polymorphism.  This is the wrong way to go.  I think generics are your friend here.

How many types do you plan to deal with?

UPDATE:

If you're just talking about String and int, here's one way you might do it.  Start with the interface XmlGenerator (enough with "foo"):

```
package generics;

public interface XmlGenerator<T>
{
   String getXml(T value);
}
```

And the concrete implementation XmlGeneratorImpl:

```
    package generics;

public class XmlGeneratorImpl<T> implements XmlGenerator<T>
{
    private Class<T> valueType;
    private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 1024;

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Integer x = 42;
        String y = "foobar";

        XmlGenerator<Integer> intXmlGenerator = new XmlGeneratorImpl<Integer>(Integer.class);
        XmlGenerator<String> stringXmlGenerator = new XmlGeneratorImpl<String>(String.class);

        System.out.println("integer: " + intXmlGenerator.getXml(x));
        System.out.println("string : " + stringXmlGenerator.getXml(y));
    }

    public XmlGeneratorImpl(Class<T> clazz)
    {
        this.valueType = clazz;
    }

    public String getXml(T value)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);

        appendTag(builder);
        builder.append(value);
        appendTag(builder, false);

        return builder.toString();
    }

    private void appendTag(StringBuilder builder) { this.appendTag(builder, false); }

    private void appendTag(StringBuilder builder, boolean isClosing)
    {
        String valueTypeName = valueType.getName();
        builder.append("<").append(valueTypeName);
        if (isClosing)
        {
            builder.append("/");
        }
        builder.append(">");
    }
}
```

If I run this, I get the following result:

```
integer: <java.lang.Integer>42<java.lang.Integer>
string : <java.lang.String>foobar<java.lang.String>
```

I don't know if this is what you had in mind.

Comment: Right now only int and string.  What would be the oop way to do this?

Comment: "Anytime you find yourself writing code of the form "if the object is of type T1, then do something, but if it's of type T2, then do something else," slap yourself." http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31

Comment: @The Feast: thanks for the link.  I think I understand what is being said but here I don't have an instance of any object.  I want foo to generate a different string for an int vs a string.  Would I have to create two instances of objects derived from some other object to do it the oop way?  It might be overkill for this case?

Comment: I've decided to go with the simple version for now since the types in question will always be primitive (int, string, etc).  However, I will definitely keep the oop way in mind.  Thanks.

Comment: @Padawan, sorry I didn't mean to be condescending - the comment by duffymo reminded me of that quote is all!

Comment: Tell more about what the method will do - it may help.

Comment: @The Feast: didn't take it that way.  Don't worry.

Comment: @duffymo: Thanks for the more detailed explanation.  I'll look it and let you know.  Thanks again.

Comment: With this kind of approach, one would generally not have getTag() but appendTag(), passing and returning the string buffer to append so as not to generate an bunch of unnecessary Strings and StringBuffers.

Comment: @duffymo: I tried this and it will be useful in other situations but this particular case I have doesn't depend on or use any actual instances of objects of type T.  Maybe I'm not thinking in a oop way yet but perhaps it'll click later.  Thanks for all your effort.

Answer (score 12):

You should pass a `Class`...

```
private void foo(Class<?> t){
    if(t == String.class){ ... }
    else if(t == int.class){ ... }
}

private void bar()
{
   foo(String.class);
}
```

Comment: Why should you pass a class and not a type? is there some reason that signatures like `method_foo(Type fooableType)` are less useful than `method_foo(Class<?> fooableClass)` ?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to pass the type, than the equivalent in Java would be

```
java.lang.Class
```

If you want to use a weakly typed method, then you would simply use

```
java.lang.Object
```

and the corresponding operator

```
instanceof
```

e.g.

```
private void foo(Object o) {

  if(o instanceof String) {

  }

}//foo
```

However, in Java there are primitive types, which are not classes (i.e. int from your example), so you need to be careful.

The real question is what you actually want to achieve here, otherwise it is difficult to answer:

> Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an instance of java.lang.Class that represents the type, i.e.

```
private void foo(Class cls)
```