# How to subset a list of certain class objects from super list?

Tags: java, oop

I have a `List<Base>` containing all objects of several implementations like `Foo` or `Bar`.
How could I extract a subset of the full list to get for example all `Foo`s?

The following works but is very ugly (dublicate code, typecasting etc).

```
class Base;
class Foo extends Base;
class Bar extends Base;

List<Base> bases;

List<Foo> getFoos() {
    List<Foo> foos = new ArrayLista<Foo>();
    for (Base base : bases) {   
        foos.add((Foo) base);
    }

    return foos;
}

List<Bar> getBars() {
    List<Bar> Bars = new ArrayLista<Bar>();
    for (Base base : bases) {   
        Bars.add((Bar) base);
    }

    return Bars;
}
```

How could this be improved?

Comment: I think this link could help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240646/how-to-pass-a-type-as-a-method-parameter-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the separate types separately from the get-go, and provide a view onto the combined list when you need it. [Guava's `Iterables#concat()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable%29) is useful for creating such a view.

---

Side note:

Unless `Bar extends Foo` or `Foo extends Bar`, calling both `getFoos()` and `getBars()` is guaranteed to throw a `ClassCastException` if `bases` contains both `Foo` and `Bar` instances.

---

Responding to digitaljoel's and Louis' comments:

```
List<Foo> getFoos() {
    return Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(bases, Foo.class));
}

List<Bar> getBars() {
    return Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(bases, Bar.class));
}
```

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate. Let's pretend this is a List of components in the order they are laid out so the interspersing of different sub-types is important (contrived, but important). Some are Buttons, some Containers, some Input, etc. getButtons is used to get a view of the buttons and apply some styling or behavior. How would he do it in that case, where he isn't going to change his internal model?

Comment: Just add `instanceof` checks to prevent the `ClassCastException`s.

Comment: @MattBall: In that case, [`Iterables.filter(Iterable, Class)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter(java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Class)) might be useful, as it does nice type-safe wrapping.

Comment: This is very nice, as I must maintain the order in that objects are added to my list. Thus I cannot split it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
private <T extends Base> List<T> getSubType(Class<T> type)
{
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (Base b : bases)
    {
        if (b.getClass().isAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            list.add((T) b);
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```